# Vehicle maintainance

Tags: toyota, camry

I have my car which is producing a popping sound from the exhaust system and the air flow system.Sometimes it starts and sometime its difficult to start today it didn't start.l am also starting it with an Hard start

Comment: Welcome to the site!  It sounds from your description that it's either "back-firing" or "misfiring".  Could you elaborate what you mean by "hard start" please?

Comment: Make, model, year and engine of the car would be useful.